# 1-1 correspondance problem

Tags: analysis

Let J = {1, 2, ...} be the nonnegative natural numbers and for n $\in$ J let J$_n$ = {m $\in$ J: m $\le$ n}.

Prove using induction that if J$_n$ and J$_m$ are in 1-1 correspondence, then m = n.

Hint: You shouldn't use "cardinal numbers" because the problem is the statement that m and n are the same cardinal number iff m = n. Assume there is a 1-1 function f from J$_m$ onto J$_n$, with m $\le$ n. It is easier to start with the case m = 0 (which means J$_m$ = $\emptyset$ ). This case should be clear by considering f$^{-1}$. For m $\ge$ 1 and a $\in $ J$_m$ there is a 1-1 map $\sigma$$_m$ from J$_m$ onto J$_m$ such that $\sigma$$_m$(a) = m and $\sigma$$_m$(m) = a. Now consider a composition of the form g = $\sigma$$_n$ $\circ$ f $\circ$ $\sigma$$_m$ and use induction.

So I've been thinking a lot about this problem and this is what I got:

Since J$_n$ ~ J$_m$ then there exists functions f and f$^{-1}$ such that f: J$_n$ $\rightarrow$ J$_m$ and f$^{-1}$: J$_m$ $\rightarrow$ J$_n$ are both bijective. Proof by induction. Induct on m and keep n fixed. Begin with the base case m = 0 then J$_m$ = J$_0$ = $\emptyset$. By f we have that J$_n$ maps to $\emptyset$ wich implies that J$_n$  = $\emptyset$ and since J$_n$ = $\emptyset$ when J$_n$ = J$_0$ we have that n = 0. Thus, m = n. Suppose inductively that if J$_n$ ~ J$_m$ then m = n. Now it remains to show that if J$_k$ ~ J$_{m+1}$ then m + 1 = k.

This is where I get stuck because I am not sure how the hint applies to the rest of the problem. I could be approaching it wrong so any comments would be appreciated. Also if anyone could check my work so far and tell me if they think its correct that would be helpful.